# Node C++ Source Code compile error

Tags: c++, node.js, eclipse

I am trying to build node.js under eclipse. ( I want to use an IDE to step through the internals of node, so I can answer some questions). I am getting a compilation error I don't understand. Below are the 2 relevant lines from the source:

```
static uint64_t counter_gc_start_time;

counter_gc_start_time = NODE_COUNT_GET_GC_RAWTIME();
```

I replaced it with the (manually expanded) macro, thus;

```
counter_gc_start_time =   (do { } while (false));
```

But I still get a compilation error:

```
/Users/concunningham/Documents/Node/node/src/node_counters.cc:81:30: error: expected expression
counter_gc_start_time =   (do { } while (false));
```

I am compiling under OS/X, 10.13.4, using compiler flag -std=c++11.

Can anyone tell me what this line of code is supposed to do ?

Comment: Why are you trying to "manually expand" the macro?

Comment: How is `NODE_COUNT_GET_GC_RAWTIME` defined?

Comment: When I first got the compile error , I replaced the macro with its definition , with a view to playing with the source , to try to fix it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  I’m working from an iPhone now , I decided to go for a beer. So forgive me for not typing the expanded macro, but it expands to the second source line I posted above. Perhaps you are getting at something else though.

Comment: Maybe try generating a preprocessed source (`-E`), in case it's getting redefined somewhere.

Comment: That is one goofy static assert. There is a conditional in the header and it actually compiles a function call if not diverted to this strange define.

Comment: @lakeweb, that should be the answer

Comment: @lakeweb, so I am missing some preprocesser definition then?

Comment: @Greycon these counters seems to be defined only for Windows, thus static assert for other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [node_counters.h](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_counters.h)

```
#ifdef HAVE_PERFCTR
#include "node_win32_perfctr_provider.h"
#else
...
#define NODE_COUNT_GET_GC_RAWTIME() do { } while (false)
#endif
```

When `HAVE_PERFCTR` is defined, `node_win32_perfctr_provider.h` is included instead of that define that will fail to compile. The definition for `NODE_COUNT_GET_GC_RAWTIME();` is in [node_win32_perfctr_provider.cc](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_win32_perfctr_provider.cc)

I don't know this library, it is just what I see by looking at the files. Where and when `HAVE_PERFCTR` gets defined is beyond what I searched. But if you have the lib on your machine, the answer is there. I'd have to download it to know more. As jbp points out, this looks like some kind of windows thing.

Comment: Hi @lakeweb. I’m building for Mac OS/x, so I’m not using the Perfectr option. So it ends up defining the macro as per my post. Which doesn’t compile, for me. But obviously node does build, so I am still puzzled. Thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: Hi, @Greycon Have you tried built the 'just out of the box' version? They say Mac is experimental but it looks like [it is supported](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md).

Comment: @lakewab, i take you point. Build with the supplied node build tools, and look a the logs... I might give that a go this evening, thanks.